# Get the selected Date and Time on KendoDateTimepicker

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-grid, kendo-datetimepicker

I am using a kendo DateTimepicker. I have a startdate and end date. when i select a start date i want the end date to be generated 30min more than the start date. For example if the selected start date is 5/11/2016 2.30PM i want the end date to be 5/11/2016 3.00PM.. Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks

kendo Code:

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <div>
          <label for="start_date" >Start Date</label>
        </div>
          <div data-container-for="data.start_date" onchange="startDate()">
         <input data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value: data.start_date" id="startDate"/>
         <input data-role="timepicker" data-bind="value: data.start_date" id="startTime"/>
       </div>
   </td>
       <td>
           <div>
              <label for="end_date">End Date</label>
           </div>
              <div data-container-for="data.end_date">
               <input data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value: data.end_date" id="endDate" />
               <input data-role="timepicker" data-bind="value: data.end_date" id="endTime"/>
             </div>
       </td>
</tr>


Function:

  function startDate() {
                var startDate = kendo.toString($("#startDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
                var startTime = kendo.toString($("#startTime").data("kendoTimePicker").value(), 'hh:mm tt')
                var endtDate = kendo.toString($("#endDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
                var endTime = kendo.toString($("#endTime").data("kendoTimePicker").value(), 'hh:mm tt')
                var StartDate = new Date($("#startDate").val());
                var futureDateTime = new Date(StartDate.setMinutes(StartDate.getMinutes() + 30));
                var End = $("#endDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(futureDateTime);
                var EndTime = $("#endTime").data("kendoTimePicker").value(futureDateTime);

    }
```

Comment: Where are you creating your datepicker? $("#start") is just a label so doing $("#start").data("kendoDatePicker") is probably null or undefined

Comment: The html part creates the kendo datepicker

Comment: Sorry i added the $("start") to the datepicker but still not working

Comment: Can you post the code in your actual aspx/ascx/cshtml? This seems like a dump after the page has rendered already. Something like shown here would be great http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/index

Comment: here is he Updated code i am getting the selected start date value to Datepicker varaible but how will we assign this to the end date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet. On click on button you get separate date and time of both datetime pickers.

```
<div>
    <input id="startDate" />
    <input id="endDate" />
    <button onclick="GetDateAndTime();">Get date an time separatly</button>
    <script>
        function GetDateAndTime() {
            var startDate = kendo.toString($("#startDate").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
            var startTime = kendo.toString($("#startDate").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(), 'hh:mm tt')
            var endtDate = kendo.toString($("#endDate").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
            var endTime = kendo.toString($("#endDate").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(), 'hh:mm tt')
            alert(startDate);
            alert(startTime);
            alert(endtDate);
            alert(endTime);
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tempDate = new Date();
            $("#startDate").kendoDateTimePicker({
                value: tempDate,
                change: onchange
            });
            $("#endDate").kendoDateTimePicker({
                value: tempDate,
            });
            $("#startDate").data("kendoDateTimePicker").trigger("change");
            function onchange() {
                var startDate = new Date($("#startDate").val());
                var newDateTime = new Date(startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 30));
                $("#endDate").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(newDateTime);
            }
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thanks it worked ...initailly when start time is 12.00am the end time is 12.30 am but when i change time to 1.00am time is not changing to 1.30am in my case with my snippet and your function

Comment: Could you please provide fiddle for same? So I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: I added the image and updated the function can you check it unable to make fiddle as it using data

Comment: Jayesh, I would prefer if you are going to copy and paste my code you should either say you did so or simply modify my code to fit the requirements. It's not a good look to do what you're doing. I believe this is the second time I've seen you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Reference this. The page you pasted still isn't quite what I was looking for.

http://dojo.telerik.com/IcENe

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/index">
<style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="example">
        <div class="demo-section k-content">

            <h4>Start Date:</h4>
            <input id="startDate" value="10/10/2011" style="width: 100%" />

            <h4>End Date:</h4>
            <input id="endDate" value="10/10/2011" style="width: 100%" />
            </p>
        </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
           // current date
          var currentDate = new Date();

            // create DatePicker from input HTML element
            $("#startDate").kendoDateTimePicker({
                 value: currentDate,
               change: onStartDateChange
            });

            // Set new datetime 30 minutes ahead
            var futureDateTime = new Date(currentDate.setMinutes(currentDate.getMinutes() + 30));
            $("#endDate").kendoDateTimePicker({
                // display month and year in the input
                value: futureDateTime,
            });

            function onStartDateChange() {
                //console.log("Change event :: " + kendo.toString(this.value()));

                // Get start date
                var startDate = new Date($("#startDate").val());
                //console.log("Start date :: " + kendo.toString(startDate));

                // Add 30 minutes
                var futureDateTime = new Date(startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 30));
                //console.log("Future date :: " + kendo.toString(futureDateTime));

                // Set time 30 minutes from now
                    $("#endDate").data("kendoDateTimePicker").value(futureDateTime);
            }

        });
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you help me in retrieving Date and Time separately if possible. The date is being added but not the time.

Comment: '
        function startChange() {
                   var currentDate = new Date();
                  
                   var Start = $("#start").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
                   var StartTime = $("#starttime").data("kendoTimePicker").value();
                   var futureDateTime = new Date(Start.setMinutes(Start.getMinutes() + 30));
                   var End = $("#end").data("kendoDatePicker").value(futureDateTime);
                   var EndTime = $("#endtime").data("kendoTimePicker").value(futureDateTime);
         
            }'